# OpenWebBeans + MyFaces + Tomcat = IllegalStateException

Tags: java, tomcat8, myfaces, openwebbeans

I'm trying to get OWB (with MyFaces & Primefaces) working on Tomcat 8.0.33. It seems like no matter how I configure things, I get this error...

```
org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces An error occured while initializing MyFaces: It's not allowed to call getBeans(Type, Annotation...) before AfterBeanDiscovery
```

...followed by this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to call getBeans(Type, Annotation...) before AfterBeanDiscovery
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectableBeanManager.checkAfterBeanDiscoveryProcessed(InjectableBeanManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectableBeanManager.getBeans(InjectableBeanManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.cdi.util.CDIUtils.lookup(CDIUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.myfaces.flow.cdi.DefaultCDIFacesFlowProvider.getAnnotatedFlows(DefaultCDIFacesFlowProvider.java:51)
    at org.apache.myfaces.flow.impl.AnnotatedFlowConfigurator.configureAnnotatedFlows(AnnotatedFlowConfigurator.java:42)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureFlowHandler(FacesConfigurator.java:1666)
    at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:608)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:416)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Based on what I have read [here](http://www.discuzfeed.com/code/lohthpss-omnifaces-does-not-recognise-openwebbean-as-cdi-after-2-0.html), [here](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013_10_01_archive.html), and [here](http://openwebbeans.apache.org/owbsetup_ee.html) (and about five bajillion other places), I have tried it *with* the Tomcat plugin dependency, *with* the OWB listener specified in `web.xml`, and even with *both* of them.  It seems like, no matter what I do, I can't seem to convince OWB to do its thing before MyFaces jumps in and starts doing its thing.  Am I missing something extraordinarily obvious or something?

```
// Maven Dependencies
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.10.72

org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-api:2.2.10
org.apache.myfaces.core:myfaces-impl:2.2.10

org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-spi:1.6.3
org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-impl:1.6.3
org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-web:1.6.3
org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-jsf:1.6.3
org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-el22:1.6.3
org.apache.openwebbeans:openwebbeans-tomcat7:1.6.3

org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec:1.0
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jcdi_1.1_spec:1.0
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-interceptor_1.2_spec:1.0
org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.2_spec:1.0

javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.2
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final

org.primefaces:primefaces:5.3
org.primefaces.themes:dark-hive:1.0.10

com.google.guava:guava:19.0
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5

org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0
```

Comment: It looks like something to be investigated in myfaces issue tracker. If you can submit an example too, that could be helpful. Please create an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES).

Answer (score 0):

you should use [ContextLifecycleListener.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.openwebbeans/openwebbeans-tomcat7/1.5.0/org/apache/webbeans/web/tomcat7/ContextLifecycleListener.java)

change addOwbListeners() method to below

```
private void addOwbListeners(StandardContext context) {
  String[] oldListeners = context.findApplicationListeners();
  LinkedList<String> listeners = new LinkedList<String>();

  // 3rd
  listeners.addFirst("org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener");
  // 2nd
  listeners.addFirst("org.apache.webbeans.web.tomcat7.ContextLifecycleListener");
  // 1st
  listeners.addFirst("org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener");

  for (String listener : oldListeners) {
    listeners.add(listener);
    context.removeApplicationListener(listener);
  }

  for (String listener : listeners) {
    context.addApplicationListener(listener);
  }
}
```

this class loaded in tomcat's common classloader. not webapp context classloader. 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

/META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
  <Listener className="mypackage.ContextLifecycleListener" />
  <Resource name="BeanManager" auth="Container"
    type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
    factory="org.apache.webbeans.container.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1" metadata-complete="false"
>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>BeanManager</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</res-type>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: won't help much I fear. Most probably it's a bug in MyFaces. I remember I found something similar and afair we also fixed it already. OWB does it right.

The reason for the Exception is to prevent random errors: If you use getBeans() during the container boot then you might likely end up with all sorts of random behaviour caused by different class scanning order, etc. We also clarified this in the CDI specification already. So this is even required by the spec.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with latest versions of the products:
Tomcat 9.0.12, MyFaces 2.3.2 and OpenWebBeans 2.0.7.

According to documentation of OpenWebBeans [Adding OpenWebBeans to your Servlet Container project](http://openwebbeans.apache.org/owbsetup_ee.html), I added the configuration listener to `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and this fixed the problem.

Note however, that according to the documentation adding the Tomcat7 plugin should fix the problem as well, but did not.